# Upgrading deployment to corda version 3.1-corda

Tags: corda

We have a cordapp jar and a web application war that depend on corda version 'corda-3.0-RC01'. Our deployment includes a corda jar of the same version. We would like to upgrade to version '3.1-corda'. As I understand, it involves performing contract upgrades on the cordapp and updating the corda jar, cordapp jars and wars in the deployment. However, is it possible to stagger the update of the cordapp (through contract upgrades) by first updating the deployed corda jar and just the webapp war? Would this require the war to be built against corda-rpc version '3.1-corda'? Could you please advise on the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the docs for upgrading to Corda3.1:https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V3.1/upgrading-cordapps.html?highlight=upgrading

However, keep in mind that Corda is currently on 4.0, and going to have another update during the summer.